# iOS Device location (iOS 8.2 and above) iPad without 3G and GPS Chip

Tags: ios, ipad, gps, wifi, latitude-longitude

I've come here today to ask a question about the use of device location on a iPad (without 3G, 4G + no GPS Chip). I'm trying to figure out why after sometime the location stops working. I'm able to pick up the location when i'm on WiFi + network selected. I'm also able to find my location when i'm on WiFi + no network selected. I've walked around Manchester (UK) and the location works fine, then I travel outside the city and location just stops working and doesn't work again.

The latitude and longitude values stop returning back and i'm no longer able to display these on the screen.

Obviously the location going to work in cities such as London and Manchester (UK) because there is WiFi spots everywhere around the City. But I don't get why the location just stops working and doesn't pick up again when I travel outside the city and into my home town.

**Devices:**

- iPad 2 + WiFi (no 3G/4G + no GPS chip)
- iPad Mini + WiFi (no 3G/4G +
  no GPS chip)

Could anyone give me some of their knowledge and explain to me how exactly the Location works on an iPad and why it just stops working?